# How to append lines to each other based on condition in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have text:

```
Fishing tour.png
Fishing tour2.png
One Day Tour.png
Sydney Adventure 3 Days Package.png
Sydney Northern Beaches Scenic Flight by Seaplane.png
Week trip.png
Weekend trip to Baku.png
Fishing tour a0HR000000B4wMUMAZ    
One Day Tour a0HR000000B4wMVMAZ    
Sydney Adventure 3 Days Package a0HR000000B4wMWMAZ    
Sydney Northern Beaches Scenic Flight by Seaplane a0HR000000B4wSuMAJ   
Week trip a0HR000000B4wMTMA    
Weekend trip to Baku a0HR000000B4wMSMAZ
```

I want to make two conditions.

1. **Replace** identical words without extension by words with extension, can be any extension (`'Fishing tour'` replace on `'Fishing tour.png'`) and remain Id as it is.
2. Words with appended number(0-9) **put on new line** with id matching to previous word identical to it (`'Fishing tour'` replace on `'Fishing tour2.png'` and remain id of `'Fishing tour'`, so this id happens twice in text).

So, desired output should be:

```
Fishing tour.png a0HR000000B4wMUMAZ   
Fishing tour2.png a0HR000000B4wMUMAZ(id is identical as on the line above)    
One Day Tour.png a0HR000000B4wMVMAZ    
Sydney Adventure 3 Days Package.png a0HR000000B4wMWMAZ    
Sydney Northern Beaches Scenic Flight by Seaplane.png a0HR000000B4wSuMAJ    
Week trip.png a0HR000000B4wMTMAZ   
Weekend trip to Baku.png a0HR000000B4wMSMAZ
```

Please, help If someone know how to do this using `awk` or `sed` or any other tool that's available in Bash.

My code attempt:

```
sed -E 's/(.+([0-9])?\..+)|.+[[:space:]]([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\1\3/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ( match($0,/[0-9]*\.[^.]+ *$/) ) {
        key = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        vals[key,++numVals[key]] = $0
    }
    else {
        key = $0
        sub(/ +[^ ]+ *$/,"",key)
        ids[key] = $NF
    }
}
END {
    for ( key in ids ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=numVals[key]; i++ ) {
            print vals[key,i], ids[key]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Weekend trip to Baku.png a0HR000000B4wMSMAZ
Fishing tour.png a0HR000000B4wMUMAZ
Fishing tour2.png a0HR000000B4wMUMAZ
Week trip.png a0HR000000B4wMTMA
One Day Tour.png a0HR000000B4wMVMAZ
Sydney Northern Beaches Scenic Flight by Seaplane.png a0HR000000B4wSuMAJ
Sydney Adventure 3 Days Package.png a0HR000000B4wMWMAZ
```

If the output order matters it's an easy tweak.

The above assumes that all of the key values can fit in memory.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this thing not from file but from output of two arrays that kept in variable? And put the final output in Associative Array with name as a key and id as a value?

Comment: Can you kindly explain what is "match" in conditional statement. Is it keyword?

Comment: `match()` is a function, see the awk man page and/or https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions. If you use GNU awk you can also run it in [debug mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Debugger) to see what each statement does and you can add `print` statements to dump tracing info if you like.